# bash find lines with integers until next string

Tags: linux, bash

I'm working with a log file, and looking for which process group is taking too much time. I'm running script each minute to check the previous times. I've come to the moment where I've got output like below:

```
Group'xyz'
0
5
1
Group'test'
0
2
0
Group'stat'
0
Group'xyz'
0
0
1
0
1
0
1
2
1
```

I want to sum values per each group to see which one takes to much time to execute. When I'm using sort -nr it sorts the strings first(group names) and then values. How to sum up those values for each  group and then print which group is taking too much time. ( in example it should print that group xyz is taking the most time to execute.

Comment: what have you tried so far? please include your attempts in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This awk one-liner should help you:

```
awk 'NR==1{t=$0;next}/^Group/{print t,s;t=$0;s=0}{s+=$1}END{print t,s}' file
```

Comment: Thank you for help. I saw that at end of the file there's an extra line starting with the word "Time" and some numbers that I would like to ommit-how can I put in this awk? Right now they are added to the last group.

Right now it looks like this:

grep "$(date --date '-1 min' | cut -d ' ' -f5 | cut -d ':' -f1,2 )" |cut -d ':' -f4,5  |cut -d ':' -f2 | tr -d ' ' | cut -d '.' -f1 | awk 'NR==1{t=$0;next}/^Group/{print t,s;t=$0;s=0}{s+=$1}END{print t,s}'